# 'data type not understood' a mistake in defining the list of column names

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to assign column names using np.dtype

I have defined a list of names

```
print fieldNameList

[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E', u'F', u'G', u'H', u'I', u'J', u'K', u'L', u'M', u'N', u'S']
```

Then, array to string

```
field_name = ', '.join(["('%s', '<f8')" % w for w in fieldNameList])

print field_name

('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', '<f8'), ('E', '<f8'), ('F', '<f8'), ('G', '<f8'), ('H', '<f8'), ('I', '<f8'), ('J', '<f8'), ('K', '<f8'), ('L', '<f8'), ('M', '<f8'), ('N', '<f8'), ('S', '<f8')
```

Then

```
inarray = np.array(tup1,
                np.dtype([field_name]))
```

I get an error

```
np.dtype([field_name]))
TypeError: data type not understood
```

When instead of a variable enter generated field_name get the desired result

```
inarray = np.array(tup1,
            np.dtype([('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', '<f8'), ('E', '<f8'), ('F', '<f8'), ('G', '<f8'), ('H', '<f8'), ('I', '<f8'), ('J', '<f8'), ('K', '<f8'), ('L', '<f8'), ('M', '<f8'), ('N', '<f8'), ('S', '<f8')]))
```

The number and names of columns depend on the input table. It defines user. Why can not the number and names of columns defined in the script.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> field_name = ', '.join(["('%s', '<f8')" % w for w in fieldNameList])
>>> field_name
"('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')"
```

makes `field_name` a string. `[field_name]` is a list containing one string.
Instead, the [NumPy dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) can be specified as a list of tuples:

```
>>> [(w, '<f8') for w in fieldNameList]
[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')]
```

---

```
fieldNameList = [u'A', u'B', u'C']
fieldNameList = [name.encode('utf-8') for name in fieldNameList]        # 1
tup1 = [(1,2,3)]
inarray = np.array(tup1, dtype=[(w, '<f8') for w in fieldNameList])
```

yields

```
array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)], 
      dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
```

---

1. Note that `fieldNameList` must be a list of byte strings -- not unicode. 
   If `fieldNameList` is a list of unicodes then you'll need to encode them first.

Comment: Thnx very much @unutbu

Comment: Apparantly you can use unicode objects as field names when you use the dictionary method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936203/1025391

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled accross this issue myself.

When you define a field name from a unicode object like this, you receive an error (as explained in the other answer):

```
>>> np.dtype([(u'foo', 'f')])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Interestingly, when you create the same dtype object using the dictionary method, it works:

```
>>> np.dtype({'names': [u"foo"], 'formats': ["f"]})
dtype([(u'foo', '<f4')])
```

For the record: I'm using Python 2.7.6, with numpy 1.13.1. This issue doesn't exist with Python 3.4.3.

Here is the corresponding entry in the github numpy issue tracker: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2407